# How can i access to mysql database from other pc?

Tags: mysql

C# i have a project which is created in visual studio and mysql as backend database. But when i run the exe file to other it says that  "mysql is missing".

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your program needs configuration items that include:

- mysql server hostname/ip
- mysql username
- mysql password
- application database name

Then your code can connect to a remote mysql database.

Comment: How can i create remote  mysql database?

Comment: How is your db configured? Is it on the LAN but on a different machine, or is it remote as in AWS or Azure remote?